# How to find all startup apps?

Tags: windows, windows-10, virus, anti-virus

So whenever I start my PC there's this pop-up that says "Windows can't find *C:\Users[Name]\etc\etc\etc*" and I tried to remove whatever was happening from Startup but couldn't find anything. I've done eerything, I used Task Manager, I navigated to the startup folder, and I even used Autorun. Heck I used CCleaner to clean Registry files as well. Yet it keeps popping up. Just yesterday I had viruses and I got rid of all of them using Avast, McAfee, Malware scanner and Immunet. And this issue has been coming ever since. How do I fix it?

Comment: You have evidently not gotten rid of all traces of the infection.

Comment: @harrymc My antivirus softwares don't show anything wrong

Comment: You should check the Task schedule, Task manager (Startup column). Or maybe it just some error from the OS? I use OneDrive and cmdline popup every system start!

Comment: @raspiduino Is there any fix for this?

Comment: @Gurmay Malvai for what? The OneDrive? I think OneDrive is just mapping the virtual disk.

Answer (score 1):

An antivirus only finds what it was programmed to find, so there is
no guarantee that your computer is not still infected.

In the hope that the virus program was deleted, and only its invocation
still remains, search for the program that is named in the error message
by using the following tools:

- [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns)
  which lists all startups and can search them all
- [RegScanner](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html)
  which can quickly search the registry
- [voidtools everything](https://www.voidtools.com/)
  which can quickly search all files of the disk after indexing it
  (Windows Explorer can also do it).

Together they will enable you to eradicate the traces left by the virus.
Hopefully the virus was eradicated, but watch for any strange happenings,
and keep on running scans by various well-known antivirus products
from time to time.

Comment: So I found a lot of results from RegScanner. Would it be safe to simply delete all the Registry keys from there?

Comment: Autoruns  is much safer and should be enough. Registry updates are dangerous, so do not delete indiscriminately. I really don't like the sound of "a lot of results", so don't do it without real understanding of what you are doing. Take backups before doing registry work, especially creating a System Restore backup. If you need advice, add the list of found keys to your question.

Comment: I can't find a single result in Autoruns, that's the problem, however I do find it in RegScanner.

Comment: Post the list if you want advice. Do NOT delete a lot of registry entries.

Comment: https://ibb.co/xzRdhHx

Comment: I posted a link. So the file its saying it can't open is Call Of Duty: WWII

Comment: Yeah, if you delete a lot, you might damage your system!

Comment: I do a google search and found out it's a game.

Comment: @raspiduino It is a game which I deleted long time back which only began to try booting up after I got a virus

Comment: This game is not dangerous. It was probably removed, just not completely. Your screenshot is unreadable, and what were you searching for?